# return code as the input value for another play

Tags: ansible, return-value

My goal is to implement 2 separate playbooks from the root main.yml, however, I would like to execute the 2nd playbook only when the 1st gives a return code of 0. Am sure this could be done in some other ways as well.

> ```
> ---
> - hosts: all
>
> - import_playbook: sftp.yml
>
> - import_playbook: reboot.yml
> ```

> ```
> ---
> - hosts: sftp01
>
>   tasks:
>     - name: create file
>       shell: touch /home/xxxxxxxxx/sftp_now
> ```

> ```
> ----
> - hosts: remote
>
>   tasks:
>
>     - name: rebooting the remote test box
>       reboot:
>         test_command: whoami
>       become: true
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way. Note, this untested response:

```
---
  tasks:
    - name: create file
      shell: touch /home/xxxxxxxxx/sftp_now
      register: touch_out

    - name: rebooting the remote test box
      reboot:
        test_command: whoami
      become: true
      when: 'touch_out.rc == 0'
```

Comment: My bad, i didnt mention that I am supposed to run each playbook on a different target host.